# Why Django auto adds permissions to group?

Tags: django, django-models, django-permissions

Currently I'm making some groups for my backend and I noticed through the admin panel that the groups have some extra permissions I did not add. What is the cause of this behavior?

**models.py:**

```
produccion_group, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name="Produccion y cuentas")
produccion_group.permissions.add(
    Permission.objects.get(codename='add_brand'),
    Permission.objects.get(codename='change_brand'),
    Permission.objects.get(codename='view_brand'),
    Permission.objects.get(codename='add_expense'),
    Permission.objects.get(codename='change_expense'),
    Permission.objects.get(codename='view_expense'),
)
produccion_group.save()
```

**Admin panel:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by adding the following block of code. Still doesn't answer the incognita of why it's added automatically, but fixes the unwanted permissions.

```
def ready(self):
    produccion_group.permissions.remove(
    Permission.objects.get(codename='add_user'),
    Permission.objects.get(codename='change_user'),
    Permission.objects.get(codename='delete_user'),
    Permission.objects.get(codename='view_user'),
    Permission.objects.get(codename='add_group'),
    Permission.objects.get(codename='change_group'),
    Permission.objects.get(codename='delete_group'),
    Permission.objects.get(codename='view_group'),
)
    produccion_group.save()
```